# Mongo full text search with score via Ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, full-text-search

In the [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#return-the-text-search-score), it says you can do this:

```
db.articles.find(
   { $text: { $search: "cake" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
)
```

That works fine when I run it from the mongo console but I can't figure out how to do that via the Ruby driver.

When I do this:

```
articles.find('$text': { '$search': 'cake' }, score: { '$meta': 'textScore' })
```

I get

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: unknown operator: $meta (2)
```

When I do

```
articles.find({ '$text': { '$search': 'cake' } }, score: { '$meta': 'textScore' })
```

I get results but it doesn't include the score and the log message doesn't show that it's using the `score: { $meta': 'textScore' }`:

```
{"find"=>"articles", "filter"=>{"$text"=>{"$search"=>"cake"}}}
```

I guess I just don't grok how the Ruby driver and Mongo CLI convert those into Mongo queries.

I'm using MongoDB version v3.2.7 and the mongo gem version 2.2.5.

Comment: You use this driver - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look to structure of `mongo` command:

```
db.collection.find(
   <query>,
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
)
```

We see that command contains two parts (in this case `find`)

1. `<query>`
2. `options hash`

Structure of command in mongo-driver very similar to mongo. But some things are not simple.

In mongo-driver we have `Mongo::Collection::View`, check ([link to source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/fac7e279b00669668c67c43d68164fac86337873/lib/mongo/collection/view.rb)):

```
articles.find({ '$text': { '$search': 'cake' } }.class # => Mongo::Collection::View
```

So after analyzing code, i found that you can use `projection` option, but it is tricky:

```
articles.find(
 { "$text" => { "$search" => "cake" } }, 
 projection: { 
   "score" => { "$meta" => "textScore" }, 
   some_field: 1
 })
```

My test was:

```
posts.find(
  { "$text" => { "$search" => "house" } }, 
  projection: { "score" => { "$meta" => "textScore" }, rooms: 1 }
)
```

Results is:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53f5c8b54465764a82fb0000'), 
 "rooms"=>2.0, 
 "score"=>0.5004448398576512}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

@farhatmihalko's answer is spot-on. To add to it, this also works:

```
posts
  .find("$text": { "$search": "house" })
  .projection(score: { "$meta": "textScore" }, rooms: 1)
```